# C# - If New DataGridView Has Same Rows With Other DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, datatable

I have 2 DataGridViews. After doing some operations in my first DataGridView, I transfer the rows ​​to my second DataGridView. Now, I want to do this. In my second DataGridView, I don't want to add rows that are the same as the first DataGridView.

My DataGridView1 looks like that:

```
                Column 1                Column2
           ---------------------------------------
               hello friends              250
               hi guys                    15
               good day                   15684
               old days                   156153
               bye bye                    6143
```

If my DataGridView2 has;

```
              hello friends               250
              bye bye                     6143
```

I don't want to add these rows.

It's my adding code:

```
      foreach (DataRow r in d.Rows)
      {
          dgw.Rows.Add(r["firstColumnFromMySQLTable"].ToString() + " " + r["secondColumnFromMySQLTable"].ToString(), r["thirdColumnFromMySQLTable"]);
      }
```

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

A DataRow is from a DataTable so I assume you have DataTables.  See code below :

```
           DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

            List<string> table2Column1 = dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Column 1")).ToList();
            DataTable dt3 = dt1.AsEnumerable().Where(x => table2Column1.IndexOf(x.Field<string>("Column 1")) >= 0).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Where should I add this code? In foreach or somewhere else?

Comment: You do not need a foreach.  The final row produces a new datatable.  Then you can make the new table the DataSource of your DGV.

Comment: Hi again. It gives error: "The source contains no DataRows”

Comment: I just created two new tables do get syntax correct.  You have to replace dt1 and dt2 with your tables.